# pickle returning class name and object memory location instead of object values

Tags: python, pickle

I am working on a college assignment about pickling a list made from a class I created. The different parts of the program must be located in different files for the assignment.

When I unpickle the class I get the object name and memory location, but not the values located in the object attributes.

This is the class located in retail.py

```
class RetailItem:

    def __init__(self, itemDescription, units, price):
        self.__itemDescription = itemDescription
        self.__units = units
        self.__price = price

    def set_itemDescription(self, itemDescription):
        self.__itemDescription = itemDescription

    def set_units(self, units):
        self.__units = units

    def set_price(self, price):
        self.__price = price
    
    def get_itemDescription(self):
        return self.__itemDescription
    
    def get_units(self):
        return self.__units
    
    def get_price(self):
        return self.__price
```

This is the file (retail2.py) where I pickle the list:

```
import pickle
import retail

itemList = []

amount = int(input('Enter amount of items: '))
counter = 1

for count in range(amount):
    item = retail.RetailItem('itemDescription', 'units', 'price')
    print('This is for item', counter)
    counter += 1
    itemDescription_ = input('Enter the description of the item: ')
    item.set_itemDescription = itemDescription_
    units_ = int(input('Enter the amount of that item: '))
    item.set_units = units_
    price_ = float(input('Enter the price of the item: '))
    item.set_price = price_
    print()
    itemList.append(item)
    #this is stored in indexes
```

This is the file (test.py) where I unpickle the list:

```
import pickle
import retail
input_file = open('itemList.dat', 'rb')
 
load = pickle.load(input_file)
print(load)
input_file.close()
print(load[0].get_itemDescription, load[0].get_units, load[0].get_price)


buy = input('Which item would you like to buy: ')
if buy not in load:
    print('That item is not found')
```

This is the result:

```
[<retail.RetailItem object at 0x000001FCFE452BC8>]
<bound method RetailItem.get_itemDescription of <retail.RetailItem object at 0x000001FCFE452BC8>> <bound method RetailItem.get_units of <retail.RetailItem object at 0x000001FCFE452BC8>> <bound method RetailItem.get_price of <retail.RetailItem object at 0x000001FCFE452BC8>>
```

What am I doing wrong? How do I get the values out of the object?

Comment: This has nothing to do with pickle, this is basic python object use. Too call a method, you need to use parentheses,  like with any other function, like `my_object.some_method()`, you are doing `my_object.some_method`, which simply evaluates to the method object

Comment: `item.set_units = units_` is not how you use a method, you would hae to do `item.set_units(units_)`. Also note, you really shouldn't be writing getters and setters in Python, although, many college courses show you that way because they were designed around languages like Java. In python, we have encapsulation without boilerplate getters and setters.